# Safari iOS 6 operation bug

Tags: javascript, ios6

I have the following problem. I'm currently developing an online game for Facebook. It's made with an HTML5 canvas and I'm using the melonJS Javascript engine.

Suddenly my game objects were not visible anymore and I even found the reason. The engine sets a flag on each object, indicating whether this object is visible. Therefore the engine checks whether the viewport (represented as a rectangle object) contains the object (also represented as a rectangle object).

This is the code of the described function ('this' is the object, 'r' is the viewport in this case):

```
/**
 * check if this rectangle is intersecting with the specified one
 * @param  {me.Rect} rect
 * @return {boolean} true if overlaps
 */
overlaps : function(r) {
return (this.left < r.right && r.left < this.right && this.top < r.bottom && r.top < this.bottom);
}
```

I know it sounds very strange, but for some reason this function returns 'false' even when it should return 'true'! But it's not a bug in the engine, and not a bug in my game. This bug only appears on the latest Safari version (Mac version unknown and iOS6 on iPad).

For some reason this bug does NOT appear, if the developer console is shown. If it's hidden, the bug appears immediately.

Does anyone know of this problem?

Comment: For better understanding: what i mean as i wrote 'should return true' is, that the function returns 'false' even when all four comparison-operations return 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still a problem, you can file a bug report on the melonJS issue tracker: https://github.com/melonjs/melonJS/issues

It may have been related to some code that has changed since this question was asked ("visible" and "in viewport" are now treated as separate things since melonJS 0.9.5)